# Compiling a GWT application for a specific relative path

Tags: java, gwt

Is there a way to compile a GWT application so that all the files are relative to a path different than the usual `/` ?

E.g.  `http://www.acme.com/` to `http://www.acme.com/app/`

I know I could play some server side tricks (based on the pattern `com.acme.app.*` of the Java class) but the problem is I am planning on hosting multiple GWT apps on the same `www` subdomain... and therefore GWT's usual pattern is `/` relative...

Any hints?

**UPDATED**: I have a way by modifying the file `Main.html` manually but I am hoping for a more automated way.  Granted that `Main.html` only needs to be modified once it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply moved the compiled gwt folder.

e.g.:

```
<module zzz.flying.spaghetti rename-to="FlyingSpaghetti">
....
</module>
```

would have the gwt compiler place the compiled code into `war/FlyingSpaghetti` . Then, I would manually move it to subfolder `war/peace/FlyingSpaghetti`.

If you have links within your gwt app that refer back to itself, you would need to make sure that those url references are relative. Even GWT RPC @RemoteServiceRelativePath annotation uses relative path - which means that you should have no problem ensuring relative url paths. Perhaps, google expects people to be able to do that (relocate a compiled module).